# Mutable anonymous struct

Tags: c++, struct, clang, constants, mutable

I want to define an aggregate with a number of `mutable` fields (to save it in `std::set` or `std::priority_queue` and modify it in future, surely saving the container invariants). I tried the following syntax and it was compiled successfully:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    struct X
    {
        mutable struct 
        {
            int i;
            int j;            
        };
    };
    X const x{};
    //x.i = 1;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Live example for `clang 3.8`.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/751630a36803c27c)

But statement `x.i = 1;` gives an error:

> error: cannot assign to variable 'x' with const-qualified type 'const X'

My intention was to group a plenty of sequential fileds and apply `mutable` keyword to the group.

Is this syntax wrong? If so, what is an intention of compiler makers to allow such a syntax if any?

#### ADDITIONAL:

Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>

int
main()
{
    struct X
    {
        mutable struct 
        {
            int i;
            int j;            
        };
        void f() const { i = 1; }
    };
    X const x{};
    //x.i = 1;
    x.f();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

gives an error too:

> error: cannot assign to non-static data member within const member function 'f'
>
> note: member function 'main()::X::f' is declared const here
>           void f() const { i = 1; }

Comment: The mutable keyword has meaning for members only inside member functions.

Comment: `X` has no data member called `i`. Are you sure this example reproduces your real use case?

Comment: @juanchopanza I sure. I **really** (trust me!) do want to group a number of fields and apply `mutable` type specifier to all of them at once.

Comment: OK, well you can't do it like that, because `X` has no member called `i`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think he uses the unnamed structure [as allowed by  C11](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html) but not by C++.  I guess that the mix of this non standard usage with the standatd C++ `mutable` will not work as expected.

Comment: @Christophe First thought in right direction, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trouble comes from the mix between the non-standard (in C++) usage of anonymous `struct` together with the `mutable`.  The latter is a storage class specifier that is meant to be used for members and not for types.

### Alternative 1:  define an intermediate member for your anonymous struct:

You can define a member that will then be mutable, according to the rules of standard C++:

```
struct X
{
    mutable struct 
    {
        int i;
        int j;            
    } y;
};
X const x{};
x.y.i = 1;
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/08dX4G)

### Alternative 2: make every members in the anonymous struct mutable:

You can otherwise define the members within the struct as being mutable.  As the anonymous struct merges these members into the enclosing struct, the mutable property will be passed on:

```
struct X
{
    struct 
    {
        mutable int i;
        mutable int j;            
    };
};
```

[Online demo](http://ideone.com/zhUwJy)

### What does the standard say ?

The standatad C++ doen't allow anonymous struct. Anonymous struct is a [compiler extension for C11 compatibility](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html).

The C++ standard allows however anonymous unions. But it sets restrictions, notably:

> **9.5/6:** A storage class is not allowed in a declaration of an anonymous union in a class scope.

So when compiling the following code:

```
  struct X
    {
        mutable union 
        {
            int i;
            int j;            
        };
    };
```

the compiler shall and will issue a very specific error:

```
prog.cpp:11:13: error: a storage class on an anonymous aggregate in class  scope is not allowed
         mutable union
```

I think that it is not consistent to allow using a storage class specifier on an anonymous struct (and apparently ignoring it) and to issues an error for an anonymous union.  According to me, this shall be reported as a compiler bug.  In anycase, you should adopt alternative 1 (portable & compliant) or alternative 2 (compiler dependent, but more consistent with the standard).

Comment: My usage is not incorrect, because of my initial needs. It can be wrong by the Standard reasons, but my intentions is clearly described. I want what I want.

Comment: @Orient Your usage *is* totally incorrect. That is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: @juanchopanza I totally agree. But if it is incorrect, why compiler allows me to define `mutable` anonymous struct?

Comment: @Orient, Coliru's GCC doesn't accept it. Clang clearly says anonymous structs are a GNU extension. Perhaps there's more information as to why it accepts `mutable` without a variable being declared (`mutable` applies to variables) in the documentation for that extension.

Comment: @chris `mutable` is applicable to data member declarations only as I know, isn't it?

Comment: @Orient It doesn't make much sense that it accepts that code. I'd even speculate that it is a compiler bug, but I'd have to check the standard first.

Comment: @Orient, That's what I said. The variable that `mutable` would apply to is missing from that declaration.

Comment: @chris I think it is a question about terms' strict definitions and our understanding of them. There is just a need to look at Standard's wording about this.

Comment: @chris I think you got the point:  mutable is a storage class specifier for members, not for types (see my edit), and the anonymous struct just presents an ambiguity in this regard (i.e. does the anonymous struct  represent a (hidden) member with a storage class specifier, or is it just syntactic sugar to group related members each having it's own storage class).

Comment: @Christophe Exactly what I meant, but can't express properly.

Comment: @Orient In the meanwhile, I've looked at what the standard says.  See edit (i.e. storage classes are not allowed on anonymous unions, so it would be inconsistent with the standard to accept them on anonymous struct, according to me).

Comment: I think there is alternative 3: to specify `mutable` type specifier for every data member I need, but avoiding superfluous anonymous struct.